# Chrome's interpretation of location.replace seems wrong

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, redirect, replace

It's a bold thing to state, but since Chrome's latest update their interpretation of window.location.replace seems wrong. I have a site loading content in an iframe, to be able to add a toolbar on top. This toolbar can be disabled. When the toolbar is disabled a cookie is set. Every time a page is loaded the cookie is checked, if the cookie is there the user is redirected directly to the site normally loaded in the iframe, like this:

```
if($.cookie("noframe")==true)
   window.location.replace='http://www.amazingjokes.com/';
```

This worked great 'till Chrome's latest update. People were sent straight to the site if they had the iframe disabled, and clicking 'back' sent them to my main page.

Not anymore...

People are now redirected back to the page loading the frame, with the cookie set they're redirected back to -in this case- amazingjokes.com. This is behavior of window.location.replace is now identical to :

```
window.location.href='http://www.amazingjokes.com/';
```

But this is not the behavior I'm looking for. I could set another cookie to track the redirect, but that's creating more and more overhead. And the 'replace' option should cover this. Is there a workaround? Or should this be reported as a bug at Chrome?

Comment: We've also seen our location.replace implementation has been broken after the last updates. Am unable to pinpoint the exact problem in order to file a bug with Chromium.